# What's row size in mysql?

Tags: mysql, myisam, parameter

What does row size mean in mysql? I have a mysql db and table in myisam and it shows

```
Space usage Type    Usage
Data    1.3     GiB
Index   429.1   MiB
Total   1.7     GiB

Row Statistics Statements   Value
Format  static
Collation   utf8_unicode_ci
Rows    22,000,001
Row length ø    63
Row size ø  83 B
Next autoindex  22,000,002
Creation    Jul 06, 2014 at 10:48 AM
Last update     Jul 06, 2014 at 10:54 AM
Last check  Jul 06, 2014 at 10:54 AM
```

I don't understand what does the **row size**  mean. I tried searching on Google, but didn't find much explanation about it.

Can I use it to get the final table size after inserting N rows, by doing

**row size * N rows  = table size ?**

Is it correct?

Let's say I am in testing phase, so I dont have much data in my table. Can this formula be used to get the table size after inserting n rows while in production phase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's the average size of each row in your table.

row size * N rows = table size

**Row size = 83 B**

**Rows = 22,000,001**

Row Size times Number of rows:

```
83 * 22000001 = 1826000083
```

Convert result in Giga Bytes:

```
1826000083 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 = 1.7
```

**Total = 1.7 GiB**

Max

Comment: you sir deserve more up votes , thanks for detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Table size is made up of 3 main factors

1. Data
2. Indexes
3. Fragmentation

Data size is simply a matter of row size by number of rows.

Index size for MyISAM is dealt with [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/key-space.html) - (key_length+4)/0.67, summed over all keys).

A great post explaining fragmentation is [here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3927871/MySQL-Data-Fragmentation---What-When-and-How.htm) and another good one is [here](http://www.dbasquare.com/2012/07/09/data-fragmentation-problem-in-mysql-myisam/). Fragmentation (indexes and actual data) increases the processing overhead (pointer chains to be resolved, [I/O thrashing](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/05/01/learning-about-mysql-table-fragmentation/) &c.). It's not that the actual amount of data increases, it just looks like that to the OS and the server. See Jaspar's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565997/in-mysql-what-does-overhead-mean-what-is-bad-about-it-and-how-to-fix-it) about comparing car maintenance with keeping fragmentation in check.